# How to prevent deadlock in concurrent T-SQL transactions?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, t-sql, concurrency, deadlock

I have a query which inserts hundreds of records. The idea behind the query is:

1. DELETE old record with `id`
2. INSERT new record with the same `id`
3. If the record with `id` not exists, value for `eternal_id` will be generated
4. If the record with `id` exists, we should save the value from the `eternal_id`
5. Query executing in transaction with **Read Committed** type

Query looks like:

```
DECLARE @id1 int = 100
DECLARE @id2 int = 200

CREATE TABLE #t(
    [eternal_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [id] [int] NOT NULL
)

DELETE FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] WITH (HOLDLOCK)
        OUTPUT
             DELETED.eternal_id
            ,DELETED.id
        INTO #t
WHERE [id] IN (@id1, @id2)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SomeTable]
            ([id]
            ,[title]
            ,[eternal_id])
SELECT main.*, ISNULL([eternal_id], NEWID())
FROM
(

    SELECT
     @id1 Id
    ,'Some title 1' Title

    UNION

    SELECT
     @id2 Id
    ,'Some title 2' Title

) AS main
LEFT JOIN #t t ON main.[id] = t.[id]

DROP TABLE #t
```

I have hundreds of threads which executing this query with different `@id`. Everything works perfectly when **record already exists** in `[dbo].[SomeTable]`, but when records with `@id` doesn't exists I am catching:

> Transaction (Process ID 73) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

So the problem appears when 2 or more concurrent threads pass the same `@id` and the record not existing in `[dbo].[SomeTable]`.
I tried to remove `WITH (HOLDLOCK)` here:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] WITH (HOLDLOCK)
        OUTPUT
             DELETED.eternal_id
            ,DELETED.id
        INTO #t
WHERE [id] IN (@id1, @id2)
```

This not hepled and I am started to catch:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__SomeTable__3213E83F5D97F3D0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SomeTable'. The duplicate key value is (49).
> The statement has been terminated.

So without `WITH (HOLDLOCK)` it works bad even when record already exists.

How to prevent deadlocks when record with `id` doesn't exists in the table?

Comment: Why are you deleting then inserting, instead of updating? An update wouldn't need the `HOLDLOCK` hint, as it would be the only operation in play.

Comment: 1. I don't understand why this is not an update 2. Not sure why you are using a temp table here, I suspect there would be less locking involved with a table variable instead 3. Does `WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK)` help? 4. Please [edit] and add index definitions for the table, the deadlock graph and share the query plan via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: While its a great ambition to try and avoid all deadlocks... its not always possible... and you can't prevent all future deadlocks from happens, because as more rows are added to tables query plans change. Any application code should have some form of retry mechanism to handle this.

Comment: @gvee thank you for your reply. Behind the scenes, update is simple `delete` and `insert` command, so deadlocks still happen. More @id, more probability for deadlock.

Comment: @DaleK thank you for your reply. I think I understand what are you talking about. Yes, I suppose I should implement some form of retry mechanism to handle this.

Comment: If the are happening frequently it would still be worth investigating them. But for that you need to inspect the deadlock graph which tells you exactly which resources were involved.

Comment: @DaleK ok, thank you. In my case deadlocks happening not frequently, so retry policy will be appropriate solution.

Comment: @Phil whilst technically correct that updates are a combination of a delete and an insert, the way in which they are performed compared to your code is wildly different.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it adds zero value to the community. OP has ignored advice and has written and accepted their own answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the comment above from @DaleK helped me the most. I will quote it:

> While its a great ambition to try and avoid all deadlocks... its not
> always possible... and you can't prevent all future deadlocks from
> happens, because as more rows are added to tables query plans change.
> Any application code should have some form of retry mechanism to
> handle this. – Dale K

So I decided to implement some form of retry mechanism to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional update of `eternal_id` can be done like this:

```
update t set
    ...
    eternal_id = ISNULL(t.eternal_id, NEWID())
from [dbo].[SomeTable] t
where t.id = @id
```

Thus you will keep the old value if it exists. No need to delete/insert. Unless you have some magic in triggers.

Comment: Ivan, thank you for your reply. Behind the scenes, update is simple `delete` and `insert` command, so deadlocks still happen. The second thing is I have a bunch of records, but your solution for 1 record.

Comment: `your solution for 1 record` this is an example of update syntax. `WHERE`, `JOIN` work here the same way as in other statements. Adjust filter to your needs.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is useful information. But concurrent updates on bunch of records still produces deadlock, so I decided to implement some form of retry mechanism to handle this.

Comment: Feel free to ask another question pointing to deadlock problem instead of some code specifics. Provide data model including indicies, sample dataset, deadlock graph. Elaborate how you open/close transactions from the side invoking these "updates" (the _threads_). Currently we are discussing your solution, not the task/problem itself which is an XY problem. Deadlocks are no unicorns, there is no magic needed to fight them.